# Вывод в TextBox без зависания

Tags: c#, wpf, ui

Во время выполнения кода в параллельном потоке генерируется **200 строк** текста(в каждой строке примерно по 20 символов), после чего там же вызывается событие, в котором через `Dispatcher` эти строки присваиваются в `TextBox`. Но увы при этом программа подвисает примерно на 500 мс. Есть ли способ выводить объемный текст в этот `TextBox` без подвисания `UI`?

Comment: добавляйте текст асинхронно и порциями, при котором время реакции UI вас устроит. Я бы еще посоветовал попробовать использовать другой графический контрол.

Comment: @Ice2burn, пытался добавлять текст разбивая его. Проблема происходит не столько даже в добавлении, как выяснилось. Чем больше текста добавляется в контрол, тем больше времени требуется на отображение и тем дольше висит `UI`. То есть если в `TextBox` будет пару тысяч строк таких, то даже добавление и удаление символа через интерфейс будет вешать окно. Какой контрол?

Comment: B текст добавляете с помощью AppendText()? Свойство UndoLimit установите поменьше.

Comment: Покажите код, а? Странно, что текстбокс один, а строк 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Медленная работа с большим объёмом текста - это давняя проблема TextBox контрола в WPF.
Если она не решается путем разгрузки контрола во времени, то остается несколько вариантов:

- использовать другой графический компонент, например [**AvalonEdit**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor)
- работать с текстом, как со списком, [**хороший пример тут**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745054/2040837)

Можно еще попробовать **FlowDocumentPageViewer**, но я не пробовал.

Comment: Вариант с AvalonEdit мне как раз подошел, но вот вопрос, есть ли в нём возможность поменять цвет для гиперссылок? Или придется описывать свой стиль?

Answer (score 0):

сделайте метод обновления текста асинхронным. В таком случае текст отобразится когда метод выполнится, а UI не зависнет. Пришлите код функции - я могу показать, как сделать ее асинхронной если что.

Comment: Текст генерируется и так асинхронно, задержка именно в момент присвоения: `textbox.Text += str;`, и выносить это в отдельный поток не вариант так как вызывается исключение где говорится что `UI` находиться в другом потоке.

Comment: Асинхронные методы могут достучаться к полям без исключения

Comment: @VladimirPaliukhovich у человека тормоза непосредственно на присвоении текста. Это присвоение *всегда* происходит в UI потоке. Так что тормоза, скорее всего, надо искать в другом -- лэйаут, объем текста и т.д.